# How to Access Specific Fields of Data from Database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I am working on a inventory software in which I want to access the ProductName and Product Price by Comparing it With the ProductCode, the Data I've Already Stored in Database table named ProductLog, the Data in Product Log is:

```
ItemNO       Productode       ProductName      ProductPrice
     1             123              lux              58
     2             321              soap             68
```

now I want that I only enter productCode in my textbook named txtProductCode, and press tab then ProductPrice(txtProductPrice) and ProductName(txtProductName) boxes fills automatically.

The code I tried to compare the Productcode and access values is:

```
  private void txtProdcutCode_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            InitializeComponent();
            string sql;

            int productCode = 0;

            productCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtProdcutCode.Text);

            sql = "";
        sql = "SELECT dbo.ProductLog.ProductName, dbo.ProductLog.ProductName";
        sql = " WHERE ProductLog.ProductCode = " + txtProdcutCode.Text + "";


            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand rs = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader sdr = null;
            clsConnection clsCon = new clsConnection();


            clsCon.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref cn);


            rs.Connection = cn;
            rs.CommandText = sql;
            sdr = rs.ExecuteReader();


            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                txtProductPrice.Text = sdr["ProductPrice"].ToString();
                txtProductName.Text = sdr["ProductName"].ToString();
            }


            //lblTotalQuestion.Text = intQNo.ToString();

            sdr.Close();
            rs = null;
            cn.Close();




            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         
        }
```

but in line `productCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtProdcutCode.Text);` it says `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Please help me out with this problem.

### EDIT:

I've also tried this code :

```
   private void txtProdcutCode_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            string sql;

          //  int productCode = 0;

            //productCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtProdcutCode.Text);

            sql = "";
            sql = "SELECT dbo.ProductLog.ProductName, AND dbo.ProductLog.ProductName";
            sql = " WHERE dbo.ProductLog.ProductCode = " + txtProdcutCode.Text + "";


            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand rs = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader sdr = null;
            clsConnection clsCon = new clsConnection();


            clsCon.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref cn);


            rs.Connection = cn;
            rs.CommandText = sql;
            sdr = rs.ExecuteReader();


            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                txtProductPrice.Text = sdr["ProductPrice"].ToString();
                txtProductName.Text = sdr["ProductName"].ToString();
            }


            //lblTotalQuestion.Text = intQNo.ToString();

            sdr.Close();
            rs = null;
            cn.Close();




            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         
        }
```

but it says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` means I am making mistake in calling database table in my query, but I am not able to find out the mistake ...

Comment: What is the value of `txtProdcutCode.Text` exactly?

Comment: it's 123 in the txtProductCode.text

Comment: So, you say `Convert.ToInt32("123");` fails? Are you sure? What `Culture` you are using?

Comment: Why are you calling `InitializeComponent` in leave event ?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes, you are right, check i've edited the question and lets see if you can help me out!!

Comment: Your next issue will be that you are reassigning the value of the 'sql' variable such that the SELECT line won't be in there, but only a WHERE clause, and your database call won't work. Use '+=' instead of '='

Comment: @DavidKhaykin can you please tell me where i am reassigning the value i am really stucked in it

Comment: The line that reads: sql = ""; The next 2 lines should start with sql += "

Comment: Please read some SQL Books first..

Comment: @DavidKhaykin you were right, i tried your additions now it's saying `The multi-part identifier "dbo.ProductLog.ProductCode" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "dbo.ProductLog.ProductName" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "dbo.ProductLog.ProductName" could not be bound.`

Comment: Also you should look up parameterized sql. The way you write your SQL statement leaves your app open to SQL Injection attack. The value of the product text box should be a parameter.

Comment: I'm going to make an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your SQL.

1. You were originally overwriting the sql variable and only ended up with a WHERE clause;
2. You don't have a FROM statement so the database doesn't know where you're trying to retrieve records from.
3. The use of AND in a SELECT statement is incorrect; you just need commas to separate the fields.
4. You're never selecting ProductPrice from the DB, but selecting ProductName twice!
5. You're not using parameterized SQL for your query, leaving your app open to SQL injection attacks.

To address this (points 1-4, I will leave point 5 for your own research),

```
  sql = "";
  sql = "SELECT dbo.ProductLog.ProductName, AND dbo.ProductLog.ProductName";
  sql = " WHERE dbo.ProductLog.ProductCode = " + txtProdcutCode.Text + "";
```

Should be

```
  sql += "SELECT ProductName, ProductPrice";
  sql += "  FROM dbo.ProductLog";
  sql += " WHERE ProductCode = '" + txtProdcutCode.Text + "'";
```

Note: This answer assumes that the value of txtProductCode.Text is an integer!

> EDIT: It turns out that the column, ProductCode, was a VarChar. For OP
>   and others reading this question, when you get SQL conversion errors
>   check your column datatype in SQL server and make sure it matches what
>   you're submitting.

That's the basics. There are many other improvements that can be made but this will get you going. Brush up on basic SQL syntax, and once you get that down, look into making this query use a parameter instead of directly placing `txtProductCode.Text` into your query. Good luck!

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type int.

Comment: Why would you put 'abc' in the textbox when you know it has to be an int?! That's a job for validation before building an SQL statement.

Comment: even i am adding 123 into the ProductCode

Comment: i am entering 123 in the product code but the compiler is giving error with abc, i don't know why is this so

Comment: Sounds like a browser caching issue. Or you're not retrieving the value of the textbox on every postback. To test my code and isolate your other non-related issues, you can add a line before your SQL statement 'txtProductCode.Text = "123"' and it will work. This is just to test/verify my code, then take it out and fix your other issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45056/discussion-between-psnlovercsharp-and-david-khaykin)

Comment: I've added " txtProdcutCode.Text = "123"; " but it still giving the same error, and i'm not able to read your comments here, stack flow is forcing me to go to live discussion

Comment: you are really a good man  bro :) helped a lot :) a good example for beginners :) thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 1):

Never call `InitializeComponent` method twice.It's creating your form and controls and it's calling in your form's constructor.Probably when you leave your textBox it's creating again and `textBox` will be blank.therefore you getting that error.Delete `InitializeComponent` from your code and try again.

Update: your command text is wrong.here you should use `+=`

```
sql += " WHERE dbo.ProductLog.ProductCode = " + txtProdcutCode.Text + "";
```

But this is not elegant and safe.Instead use [paramatirezed queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection =  cn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.ProductLog.ProductName,dbo.ProductLog.ProductName WHERE dbo.ProductLog.ProductCode = @pCode";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCode", txtProdcutCode.Text );
```

Comment: You still have an AND statement copied from his original SELECT and no FROM statement; it won't work that way. His SQL is too messed up!